# How to use XSL to sort elements by child element names

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to be able to sort some elements first by the name of some of their child elements, and then by an attribute.

Here is an example. I have simplified it from my actual requirement so hopefully that doesn't cause more confusion that it solves. The real requirement has a number of other elements as siblings to the '`Animals` with their own sorting requirements but this fragment in particular is giving me grief.

**Before Transformation**

```xml
    <Animals>
      <Animal Value="20160.17">
        <Identifier id="1" />
        <Pig><!-- more elements inside here--></Pig>
      </Animal>
      <Animal Value="5000.40">
        <Identifier id="2" />
        <Cow><!-- more elements inside here--></Cow>
      </Animal>
      <Animal Value="63.44">
        <Identifier id="3" />
        <Pig><!-- more elements inside here--></Pig>
      </Animal>
      <Animal Value="4800.40">
        <Identifier id="4" />
        <Cow><!-- more elements inside here--></Cow>
      </Animal>
    </Animals>
```

**Desired Transformation**

I would like each `Animal` element sorted so that all `Animal`s with a `Cow` child come first, followed by all `Animal`s with a `Pig` child. Within each of those categories, they should be sorted numerically by the `Animal`'s `Value` attribute.

**After Transformation**

```xml
    <Animals>
      <Animal Value="4800.40">
        <Identifier id="4" />
        <Cow><!-- more elements inside here--></Cow>
      </Animal>
      <Animal Value="5000.40">
        <Identifier id="2" />
        <Cow><!-- more elements inside here--></Cow>
      </Animal>
      <Animal Value="63.44">
        <Identifier id="3" />
        <Pig><!-- more elements inside here--></Pig>
      </Animal>
      <Animal Value="20160.17">
        <Identifier id="1" />
        <Pig><!-- more elements inside here--></Pig>
      </Animal>
    </Animals>
```

**Attempt**
I'm pretty new at XSL and my best attempt so far doesn't seem to take the Cow/Pig elements into account. It only sorts by the `Value` attribute:

```xml
  <xsl:template match="Animals">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Animal">
          <xsl:sort select="name(*) = 'Cow'" />
          <xsl:sort select="name(*) = 'Pig'" />
          <xsl:sort select="@Value" data-type="number" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your instruction:

```
<xsl:sort select="name(*) = 'Cow'" />
```

doesn't do anything because the expression:

```
name(*)
```

returns the name of the **first** child element - which is "Identifier" for **all** `Animal` nodes.

Try perhaps:

```
<xsl:sort select="name(*[2]) = 'Cow'" order="descending"/>
```

(The order must be `descending` because alphabetically "true" comes after false".)

Alternatively, you could just apply templates separately for each category:

```
<xsl:template match="Animals">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Animal[Cow]">
            <xsl:sort select="@Value" data-type="number" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Animal[Pig]">
            <xsl:sort select="@Value" data-type="number" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: thanks, i went with the second option of separate `apply-templates` as the order of the child elements is not guaranteed. i had actually tried something like that previously but got the value for the `select` attribute wrong. so it seems like i need to work on my xpath skills, rather than my xslt skills...